# What sushi-like dish consists of various fish in a light sauce?

Tags: sushi

I recently ate at a sushi restaurant where we just asked for "chef's choice," so we ended up with some dishes and rolls I was not familiar with.  The first one was small pieces of various fish tossed together with a light sauce.  Is there a name for this dish/preparation?

Comment: Can you describe the sauce?

Comment: I can't really place it since it was a pretty light sauce.  I'm more curious if there's a general term for fish (without rice) tossed together and eaten by itself.

Answer (score 3):

In general, slices of raw fish or other meats are called sashimi.  These are often served un-sauced, but occasionally they are served brushed with any number of soy-based sauces.

From your description, you could also be describing a Japanese-inspired version of a dish very common in Hawaii called [Poke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poke_%28Hawaii%29).  Poke is most often made with tuna, but could also be made with other fish or seafood.  The other ingredients included in Poke are highly variable.

Comment: That's the closest things I've seen.  It wasn't slices, so I'm not sure I'd call it sashimi.